# How do I change the text of a div when I hover over a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

**What I have:**

8 numbered boxes in a row. 
I'm not allowed to use jQuery.

**What I want to do:**

When the user hovers a numbered box, text changes dynamically inside a div element depending on which box is being hovered on.

**Example:**

If user hovers over Box 1, the text inside the div element says "Hello"

If user hovers over Box 2, the text inside the div element (same as before) says "World"

Edit: the closest I have is text changing if the user clicks on a button:    http://jsfiddle.net/pVN2a/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>BluePad</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #button1 {
      background-color:red;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    #button2 {
      background-color:green;
      display:inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="button1">
    Click 1
  </div>
  <div id="button2">
    Click 2
  </div>
  <div id="textResults">
    Click on a button to change text
  </div>

  <script>
    // when #button1 is clicked...
    document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // change text of #textResults
      document.getElementById("textResults").innerHTML ="Hello World";
    });

    // when #button2 is clicked...
    document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // change text of #textResults
      document.getElementById("textResults").innerHTML ="Just Clicked #button2";
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I supposed to use .onMouseEvent in conjunction with some sort of event listener? Sorry, I'm totally new to this. :(

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of your code? It will make it much easier.

Comment: Do you want us to code it for you?

Comment: Write handlers for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Comment: I literally don't have anything - I don't know how to do this. The closest I have is this, and the text changes by clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=G1QBANLGOP

Comment: why aren't you allowed to use javascript? you either work for something like 'ft.com' who shy away from using 'god objects' in there component ecosystem, or this is a school project. School project is my guess. Rephrase your question perhaps to "how do i change the text of a div when I hover over a button", and then use that answer to create your full solution to your problem.

Comment: Please post a regular jsfiddle, not a collaboration.

Comment: Regular fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pVN2a/

Answer (score 2):

Edited to fit OP's request to change content of a singular box based on hover of other boxes.  Using the general sibling combinator, we can select a div with the class results when a box is hovered.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xz55K/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">1</div>
    <div class="box2">2</div>

    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box1, .box2 { display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ccc; }

.results {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.box1:hover ~ div.results:before {
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "Hello";
}

.box2:hover ~ div.results:before {
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "World";
}
```

Using the [General Sibling Combinator](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/general).

Comment: I think he wants them all to put the message in the same DIV, not the DIV you're hovering over.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree, "If user hovers box1 "IT" says Hello, etc..."

Comment: What about "text changes inside a div element depending on which box is being hovered over"? "IT" refers to "a div element", not the box hovered.

Comment: Sorry I clarified for you guys - text inside the same div changes dynamically depending on which box is being hovered over. Does that help?

Comment: Using `content` is not intended for actual **content** it should only be used for styling and in conjunction with pseudo elements.

Comment: @Barmar OP clarified, I have edited post to represent the new situation.

Comment: @Ochre See the above for a pure CSS solution.  Note that the "content" property is not intended for content, but I assume this is for a school project or something, so as a proof of concept, this is probably acceptable.

Comment: @Michael that did the trick. Thank you SO, SO much. I could cry right now, really.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `onmouseover`, that's not jQuery.